# How to convert list to csv file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, export-to-csv

How to convert list to csv format in python
I tried it to first convert into a dataframe but was not successful
Can anyone please help

```
list = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
header = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

to

csv:

```
a | b | c | d |
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this?

```
import csv

stuff = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
header = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]


with open("stuff.csv", "w") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter="|")
    w.writerow(header)
    w.writerows(stuff)
```

Output:

```
a|b|c|d
1|2|3|4
5|6|7|8
9|10|11|12
```